# Understanding caffe library

Tags: neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to understand the [caffe library](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/). For that I run through step by step for feature_extraction.cpp and classification.cpp.

In those cpp files, I found out `layers, prototxt file, caffemodel, net.cpp,  caffe.pb.cc, caffe.pb.h`files.

I know caffe is formed using different layers. So those layer files inside layer folder are used.

prototxt file is meant for the structure of a particular network such as googlenet, alexnet etc. Different net has different structure.

caffemodel is the trained model using caffe library for a specific type of net structure.

What do those net.cpp, caffe.pb.cc do? I mean how to understand their roles in forming this caffe deep learning network.

Comment: There is a good tutorial for caffe.Please see (http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understand correctly that caffe implements deep learning by stacking "layers" one on top of the other to form a "net".

**`'net.cpp'`**
Each layer works as a "functional block" and its behavior/implementation is defined in `src/caffe/layers/<layer>.cpp`, `src/caffe/layers/<layer>.cu` and `include/caffe/layers/<layer>.hpp`.
The code that actually "stack" all the layers into a net can be found (mostly) in `net.cpp`.

**`'caffe.pb.h'`, `'caffe.pb.cc'`**
In order to define the specific structure of a specific deep net architecture (e.g., AlexNet, GoogLeNet, ResNet etc.) caffe uses [protocol-buffers](/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers) library. The specific format of caffe protocol buffer is defined in [`src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto). The `caffe.proto` is "compiled" using [google protobuffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) compiler to produce `'caffe.pb.h'` and `'caffe.pb.cc'` c++ code for parsing and processing caffe `prototxt` and `caffemodel` files.

Comment: I thought 'caffe.pb.h', 'caffe.pb.cc' are generic structure of the deep net and individual structure like AlexNet, GoogLeNet, ResNet etc. are formed using prototxt file. That prototxt file specifies structure of a particular Net like AlexNet or GoogLeNet. Based on the prototxt file, using net.cpp, a network is formed in run time using those generic 'caffe.pb.h', 'caffe.pb.cc' generic structures. Isn't it true?

Comment: According to what you said "The specific format of caffe protocol buffer is defined in src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto. ", all those structures like AlexNet, GoogLeNet, ResNet etc.are already fixed inside  'caffe.pb.h', 'caffe.pb.cc'. Let say if I want to form a new prototxt file for a different net structure, it is not possible?

Comment: @batuman you can think of it as caffe.proto defines a "language" and caffe.pb.* translate this "language" so it can be processed in c/c++ . you can write your own nets in prototxt without the need to write or compile any c++ code

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood.

Comment: Is there a doc for the layers/<layer>.cpp files. Especially for someone coming from a non cpp background. How to understand custom implementations. like : https://github.com/tonghe90/textspotter/blob/master/caffe/src/caffe/layers/attention_lstm_layer.cpp